# I cannot add the one arraylist into another

Tags: java, android

Actually I have one filtered array. I want to store that `ArrayList` in another `ArrayList`, but it is not adding. I am saving one model to another. because I want only that `filteredlist`.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ComboViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Products> catList;
    private ArrayList<FilteredCategorymodel> filterList;


    Context context;
    int count = 0;
    //    ArrayList<FilteredCategorymodel> filterModel;
    SharedPrefrences sharedPrefrences;

    boolean isClicked = true;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Products> catList) {
        this.catList = catList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ComboViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.combo_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ComboViewHolder(itemView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ComboViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final Products products = catList.get(position);
        Log.e("Products Items::::", products + "");
        holder.mProductName.setText(products.getProduct_name());
        holder.mProductDescription.setText(products.getProduct_description());
        holder.mDescription.setText(products.getRecipe_method());
        holder.mPrice.setText(products.getPrice());


        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(Constants.Image_Path + products.getProduct_image())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_focus_light) // optional
                .error(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_dark)         // optional
                .into(holder.mPImage);

        holder.mPImage.setTag(holder);

        holder.btnIncrese.setTag(position);
        holder.btnDecrese.setTag(position);


        holder.btnIncrese.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int mPosition = (int) v.getTag();
                Log.e("mPosition~", mPosition + "~" + position);
                count = catList.get(mPosition).getCount() + 1;


                for (int i = 0; i < catList.size(); i++) {

                    filterList = new ArrayList<FilteredCategorymodel>();
                    filterList.add(catList.get(i));
                }

                basketCount = basketCount + 1;
                catList.get(mPosition).setCount(count);
                holder.mQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(products.getCount()));
                ProductActivity.updateSum(basketCount);
            }
        });

        holder.btnDecrese.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                int mPosition = (int) v.getTag();
                if (catList.get(mPosition).getCount() < 1) {
                    holder.mQuantity.setText("0");

                } else {
                    count = catList.get(mPosition).getCount() - 1;
                    basketCount = basketCount - 1;
                    catList.get(position).setCount(count);

                    Log.e("COUNT::::", count + "");
                    holder.mQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(products.getCount()));

                    ProductActivity.updateSum(basketCount);
//                    sharedPrefrences = new SharedPrefrences();
//                    sharedPrefrences.addFavorite(context, catList.get(mPosition));
//                    Toast.makeText(context, "Fave",
//                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    Log.e("COUNT::::", count + "");
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return catList.size();
    }
```

Comment: be more precise please...where do You try that (codesnippet?), do You get an error or is the list just empty etc. ....only posting the whole code can´t give us enough information...if You get an error, please post logcat output too...

Comment: have you tried debugging with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Because every time you create new arraylist in loop.
Do it in this way.

```
holder.btnIncrese.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int mPosition = (int) v.getTag();
            Log.e("mPosition~", mPosition + "~" + position);
            count = catList.get(mPosition).getCount() + 1;

             filterList = new ArrayList<FilteredCategorymodel>();
            for (int i = 0; i < catList.size(); i++) {


                filterList.add(catList.get(i));
            }

            basketCount = basketCount + 1;
            catList.get(mPosition).setCount(count);
            holder.mQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(products.getCount()));
            ProductActivity.updateSum(basketCount);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @justDroid actually its saying add(model) in arraylist cannot be applied like that ...

Comment: both arraylist having different datatype. your catlist array is of Product type and other list is of different  type.

Comment: @user2806221: You should read little bit about OO Programming.

Answer (score 1):

From this too less information, I guess You are trying to add some values to Your `filterList`. The problem is, that everytime Your are going through the loop, You are creating a new `ArrayList`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < catList.size(); i++) {

                filterList = new ArrayList<FilteredCategorymodel>();
                filterList.add(catList.get(i));
            }
```

You have to init the `filterList` first, don´t do this inside the loop. Your loop must look like this:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < catList.size(); i++) {

               filterList.add(catList.get(i));
            }
```

it´s also important what You trying to reach. If You just want to fill a new list if the button is clicked, then init Your list inside `onButtonClick` outside the loop. But if You want to fill that list again and again and the values should persist, then init the list inside Your constructor.

But also, in Your case, this will not work, because `filterList` is from type **"FilteredCategoryModel"** and catList is from type **"Product"**. You cannot fill an ArrayList with a wrong type.

Comment: then how to handle this one..i want to store that in another arraylist

Comment: what is the goal for that other list? You have to create a similar list like this: ArrayList<Products> filterList;

Comment: in catlist i have all the products, but in filterlist i am getting which ever count is more than one. so that i can update in cart quantity. i am using viewpager if i save that quantity in global variable count is saving but other informations like product name and all not displaying.

Comment: now it will be difficult. Just understand, we are not included in Your project. You are creating this project and You know a lot more than we. We have no idea about what You mean with "products" and all this. You should explain a little bit more, maybe with a clear example.

Comment: actually i have a viewpager, each pager positon having one listview with certain food item. here we can increase the quantity of the product. if i increase the quantity in the list it ll be added in the cart(it is in activity) also. Increase button is in addapter. my problem is if i increase the quantity in one position cart is updating if i increase the another position quantity again it ll start from 1. i have used global varible for that count but that each row has to be taken to next activity also. this is the issue

Comment: this are two different problems You have. You shoud first clear the problem which You asked for. And if this is solved, ask a new question..otherwise all this going topsy-turvy....

Comment: it´s just an assumption, but You should try catList.get(i).getCount() inside Your loop. Maybe this is what You want....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add one `ArrayList` data into another you don't need to use loop, Use `addAll()` of `ArrayList`. Please check below example.

```html
ArrayList<YourClass> a = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<YourClass> b = new ArrayList<>();
b.addAll(a);
```

It will add all data of `b` into `a`.